# Roblox Studio: NPC Humanoid, disabling climbing

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm very new to Roblox  studio and trying to get some basic functionality working. I am spawning some NPCs, and I would like to prevent them from climbing ladders. After reading documentation, it seems I should be able to do this by using `Humanoid:SetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing, false)`. I am inserting that code right after I create the NPC as follows:

```
local function spawnEnemy()
    local enemy = ServerStorage.Enemies.Zombie:Clone()
    enemy.Parent = workspace.Enemies

    print("Setting climbing to false")
    enemy.Humanoid:SetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing, false)
    print(enemy.Humanoid:GetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing))
    enemy.Humanoid.StateEnabledChanged:Connect(function()
        print("state changed")
    end)    
end
```

The output as I start the game looks like:

```
  Setting climbing to false
  false
```

This is just what I would expect, and also note it does not output "state changed" so I know that no other part of the code is interfering.

However, this doesn't actually prevent the NPC from climbing, and in fact if I immediately type into the console (where it says "Run a command" at the bottom of roblox studio) this command:

`print(workspace.Enemies.Zombie.Humanoid:GetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing))`

The output is `true`.

Why doesn't the variable "stick"? Do I need to put this code somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetStateEnabled doesn't seem to replicate to the client. Your Run-a-command command executes against the client's workspace, and there it is still true.

If you put the same on the server (say add the following into a workspace script):

```
spawn(function()
    while (true) do     
        print(workspace.Enemies.Zombie.Humanoid:GetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing))
        wait(0.5)
    end
end)
```

...you'll see that on the server, that property is in fact false.

Update:

to set it on the client, you can just hook up a handler on your Enemies folder, that will always set the Humanoid's climbing state for all your zombies:

```
workspace.Enemies.ChildAdded:Connect(function(child)
    if (child.Name == "Zombie") then
        child:WaitForChild("Humanoid"):SetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Climbing, false)
    end
end)
```

just put that above into a LocalScript in StarterPlayerScripts.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful — I didn’t realize the Run-a-command window executes on the client. How would I go about getting SetStateEnabled to replicate to the client?

Comment: You can replicate it using a RemoteEvent, but if you just always want to disable it, you could just do it in a LocalScript. I'll update the answer above

Comment: btw I'm also fairly new to Roblox and it baffles me that the decision whether the NPC climbs or doesn't is based on a flag on the server AND client. But I duplicated your issue with an off the shelve model. Seems like a hole for hackers. But again, I'm not a pro here so there might be a better way to do this with a server-side script. Looks like others have noticed the lack of replication, though: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/setstateenabled-does-not-replicate/240041